# How to create a `MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan` method that uses `in` instead of `ref` parameter?

Tags: c#

[`MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createreadonlyspan) has this signature:

```cs
public static ReadOnlySpan<T> CreateReadOnlySpan<T> (ref T reference, int length);
```

Notice that it requires a `ref` parameter. In other words you can't use it to do this:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 512)]
struct LargeStruct
{}

class Program
{
    static readonly LargeStruct Blob = default;
    
    static byte GetSomethingFrom(in LargeStruct blob)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(in blob, 1));
        //                                                                               ^^^^^^^ Argument is 'in' while parameter is declared as 'ref'
        return span[5];
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSomethingFrom(in Blob));
    }
}
```

Of course I cannot take a `ref` of `Blob` because it's a readonly field.

So I'm left with doing something like this:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 512)]
struct LargeStruct
{}

class Program
{
    static readonly LargeStruct Blob = default;

    static unsafe byte GetSomethingFrom(in LargeStruct blob)
    {
        fixed(LargeStruct* pointer = &blob)
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(new ReadOnlySpan<LargeStruct>(pointer, 1));
            return span[5];
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSomethingFrom(in Blob));
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to encapsulate this behavior into a method having the following signature:

```cs
public static ReadOnlySpan<T> CreateReadOnlySpan<T> (in T reference, int length);
```

## My attempt

Here is my attempt so far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class MemoryMarshal2
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<T> CreateReadOnlySpan<T>(in T value, int length)
        where T : unmanaged
    {
        fixed(T* pointer = &value)
        {
            return new ReadOnlySpan<T>(pointer, length);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure this usage of the `fixed` keyword is appropriate. The documentation [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement#:%7E:text=Pointers%20to%20movable%20managed%20variables%20are%20useful%20only%20in%20a%20fixed%20context)

> Pointers to movable managed variables are useful only in a `fixed` context.

...and yet here I am "leaking" that pointer out of the `fixed` context (through the returned `ReadOnlySpan`). And I *think* the `Blob` variable in my examples above could be moved by GC?

Comment: For what it's worth, .NET's `CreateReadOnlySpan` is implemented as returning `new ReadOnlySpan<T>(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in reference), length)`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Ah, that _is_ interesting. For posterity, here's [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/MemoryMarshal.cs,8f6df82c8a965f04)

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Unfortunately that constructor for `ReadOnlySpan` is internal. But one can always do `MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in value), length)`. Some confirmation would be nice that this is a correct implementation

Comment: I can't see any way that would not be safe, as the result is still read-only. I suggest you post that as an answer to your own question

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Not anymore https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/MemoryMarshal.cs#L235 I'd love to know when it changed but can't find it.

Comment: @Charlieface The link in my comment above was working when I posted it, so something must have changed since then

Comment: Isn't this a bug in the API design? I'll submit a bug ticket if time permits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (simpler?) solution:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class MemoryMarshal2
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static ReadOnlySpan<T> CreateReadOnlySpan<T>(in T value, int length) =>
        MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in value), length);
}
```

Doesn't require `unsafe`, and does pretty much exactly what `MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan` [does](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2dcd5bf697538d6b3a1cf5f00888114fe3d97e9a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/MemoryMarshal.cs#L243).