# (single) Char to ReadOnlySpan<char>

Tags: c#

How to turn a `char` into `ReadOnlySpan<char>`?`

I know those ways

```
char fooChar = 'a';
ReadOnlySpan<char> fooReadOnlyCharFromString = fooChar.ToString(); //will implicitly cast
ReadOnlySpan<char> fooReadOnlyCharFromArray = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(new [] { fooChar });
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PxjABV

I wonder if there is a solution without creating an array or string.

Comment: You could always `Span<char> foo = stackalloc char[] {fooChar};` which will cheaply reserve space on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent the allocations that happen here:

```
char fooChar = 'a';

// String allocation
ReadOnlySpan<char> fromString = fooChar.ToString();

// Array allocation
ReadOnlySpan<char> fromArray = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(new[] { fooChar });
```

Then your options seem to be:

.NET 7's new [`ReadOnlySpan<char>(in T reference)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-readonlyspan-1-ctor(-0@)):

```
// .NET 7
ReadOnlySpan<char> fromSingleElement = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(/*in*/ fooChar);
```

Or using [a pointer and a length of 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-readonlyspan-1-ctor(system-void*-system-int32)) in an unsafe context:

```
// Pointer (/unsafe, non-CLS-compliant)
unsafe
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> fromPointer = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(&fooChar, 1);
}
```

Or using [`MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan<T>(ref T reference, int length)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createreadonlyspan?view=net-7.0) (requires `ref`):

```
// System.Memory.dll - ref
ReadOnlySpan<char> fromMemory = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref fooChar, 1);
```

Or, and that's [what the .NET 7-introduced constructor ultimately calls](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b0fa1896d7807cbee88180349cbcf6fc49a51d4e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ReadOnlySpan.cs#L116), see also [How to create a `MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan` method that uses `in` instead of `ref` parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493236/how-to-create-a-memorymarshal-createreadonlyspan-method-that-uses-in-instead), with an `in` if you can't use `ref`:

```
// System.Memory.dll - in
ReadOnlySpan<char> fromMemoryIn = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref Unsafe.AsRef(/*in*/ fooChar), 1);
```

Comment: What is the significance of `in` at option 3? Does it prevent a copy of the `char` value?

Comment: Just tested it and no that's not it. The `char` is used by reference regardless of `in`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride the `in` modifier *at the call-site* is optional and assumed automatically even if omitted, if it specified on the receiving method; so yes: it is pass by ref and referring to a span over the same memory space as the `fooChar` local. The only time `in` being present or absent matters is when there are two overloads - one with `in` and one without; then the one without is selected unless `in` is specified. You can verify this by doing: `var span = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(fooChar); fooChar = 'x'; Console.WriteLine(span[0]); // x`